# How to fix "Error: Cannot find symbol" when creating an object?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

I don't understand how my compiler cannot find the class `Weight`, considering didn't I already make it in my `public boolean checkWeight` method? The compiler points to the line:

```
`Weight first = new Weight();`
```

and

```
`Weight second = new Weight();`
```

---

```
public class Guard {

    int stashWeight;

    public Guard ( int maxWeight ) {
        this.stashWeight = maxWeight;
    }

    public boolean checkWeight (Weight maxWeight) {
        if ( maxWeight.weight >= stashWeight ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        Weight first = new Weight();
        first.weight = 3000;
        Weight second = new Weight();
        second.weight = 120;

        Guard grams = new Guard(450);
        System.out.println("Officer, can I come in?");
        boolean canFirstManGo = grams.checkWeight(first);
        System.out.println(canFirstManGo);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Officer, how about me?");
        boolean canSecondManGo = grams.checkWeight(second);
        System.out.println(canSecondManGo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the right `Weight` class?

Comment: where is your Weight class

Comment: I may have blanked out. My newbie mind thought, for some unknown reason, that I already made my weight class when I did: public boolean checkWeight (maxWeight Weight ). Thanks for the heads up all

Answer (score 0):

you should define the `Weight` class like this:

```
public class Weight {

    public int weight;

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Officer, can I come in?
true

Officer, how about me?
false
```

Or import your `Weight` class using `import` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

your Weight class is missing in your code  See the below code

```
class Weight {

    public int weight;

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

public class Guard {

    int stashWeight;

    public Guard(int maxWeight) {
        this.stashWeight = maxWeight;
    }

    public boolean checkWeight(Weight maxWeight) {
        if (maxWeight.weight >= stashWeight) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weight first = new Weight();
        first.weight = 3000;
        Weight second = new Weight();
        second.weight = 120;

        Guard grams = new Guard(450);
        System.out.println("Officer, can I come in?");
        boolean canFirstManGo = grams.checkWeight(first);
        System.out.println(canFirstManGo);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Officer, how about me?");
        boolean canSecondManGo = grams.checkWeight(second);
        System.out.println(canSecondManGo);

    }
}
```

**output**

**

```
Officer, can I come in?
true
Officer, how about me?
false
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Is your Weight class in a different package?
What's the access modifier of the Weight class?

Please verify above and have a look in below document.

[Access Modifiers](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/access-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. The method parameter "maxWeight" is of type "Weight" for which Java is unable to find the definition to resolve your program dependencies. Failing to find the class over classpath will lead to the error "Cannot find symbol".
   You may want to define the class "Weight" and import it, like others have responded to you.
2. Do you really need the "Weight" class? You are simply comparing the passed argument with the "Guard's" stashWeight.

Your public method could simply be:

```
public boolean checkWeight(int maxWeight) {
        return maxWeight >= stashWeight;
```

}

And the main method could be updated as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstWeight = 3000;
    int secondWeight = 120;

    Guard grams = new Guard(450);
    System.out.println("Officer, can I come in?");
    boolean canFirstManGo = grams.checkWeight(firstWeight);
    System.out.println(canFirstManGo);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Officer, how about me?");
    boolean canSecondManGo = grams.checkWeight(secondWeight);
    System.out.println(canSecondManGo);

}
```